# passing formula from vba to cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-r1c1-notation

I am trying to pass formula in Excel cell using Excel VBA:

```
Mt_1 = "trade-508-cd"

bpTargetRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*""&Mt_1&""*"",RC[-1])),""1"",""0"")"
```

When running the above the cell is having folrmula:

> *`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&@Mt_1&"*",B2)),"1","0")`*

But it should be:

> **`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*trade-508-cd*",B2)),"1","0")`**

Comment: Count your quote-marks carefully, and include some spaces around the ampersands when you concatenate; there's a *reason* the whole line shows up in green when you look at it…

Comment: Is `Mt_1` a VBA variable?

Comment: @Chronocidal when I give: `""*""" & Mt_1 & """*""`, it gives *1004* error code and `""*""""" & Mt_1 & """""*""` returns: ***`"*""trade-508-cd""*"`***

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, as it will be dynamic on production.

Comment: Then, test the way I suggested in my answer...

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly understood what is the formula you need. Please, try the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
   Dim Mt_1 As String: Mt_1 = "trade-508-cd"
   bpTargetRange.Formula2R1C1= "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*" & Mt_1 & "*"",B2)),""1"",""0"")"
```

My answer supposes that `Mt_1` is a VBA variable...

Comment: why 3 after `Mt_1 &` ? Also space?

Comment: @selet What 3? Double quotes? If yes, VBA needs to double the necessary one and another one for the string start... Doesn't it work as you need?

Comment: yeah double quotes, and I thought it's a typo so I tried: `""*" & Mt_1 & "*""` and it worked. I'll also try the orignal

Comment: it gives 1004 error when trying it

Comment: Please, try the updated code. And use `Formula2R1C1` as suggested, if it inserts "@" character.